# change background color of select2.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I used `select2.js(3.4.5)` for my previous project and now I need to make some changes into it. it's not possible to upgrade version of `select2` now.

I need to change the `background color` of a `select2` search box, I tried it but I can't please see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hiren_Mangukiya/6dsqrwgf/) or snippet. I want `background-color:red` after user select option from `select box`.

I try to apply CSS all the elements using `jquery`

`$('.select2-choices').attr("style",'background-color:#EA4335 !important');

 $('.select2-choices > *').attr("style",'background-color:#EA4335 !important');`

you can see in my code also.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.css'>


<div class="container-fluid">
<select id="e2_2" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%" class="select2-multi-col">
  <optgroup label="Eastern Time Zone">
   <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
   <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
   <option value="FL">Florida</option>
   <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
   <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
   <option value="ME">Maine</option>
   <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
   <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
   <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
   <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
   <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
   <option value="NY">New York</option>
   <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
   <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
   <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
   <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
   <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
   <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
   <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
   <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.min.js'></script>
  
  <script>
    $("#e2_2").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a state or many…"
});

/* apply js to select box to change background color */
$('document').ready(function(){
      
      $('.select2-choices').attr("style",'background-color:#EA4335 !important');

      $('.select2-choices > *').attr("style",'background-color:#EA4335 !important');
    }); 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try adding style to the class `select2-choices` 
like 
`.select2-choices {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(100%, #EA4335), color-stop(100%, #EA4335)) !important;
}`.
i think this will work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771824/select2-change-background-color

Comment: it's not working in my case @SarunUK